# Getting error code 200 for google assistant on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am getting the following errors:
https://embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/v1alpha2/projects/rpiassistant-f01c3/devices/B65EF05D34859770BDEBF646E84D89F1 200
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
{'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
[2509:2526:ERROR:http_client_with_backoff.cc(113)] Retrying request with http_status=200 request_id=0

The above URL returned as follows:
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}

Please note that I have enabled the API still getting this error please help

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP status code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) is not an error. Rather, it is an indication that the HTTP request was successful.

When the sample is making that call, it includes authorization that tells the Google Assistant SDK server that it is you making this request. When you just open it up in a browser, the server doesn't know it is you and returns a [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) for unauthorized access.

AFAIK, this is working as intended and you should be able to run the sample without issue.